# Excel Conditional validated data input

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

### Problem

I'm using Microsoft Excel for data collection.

I have an excel sheet with two columns.

**Column A - List**

The first column is a list I created with Data Validation.
The choices are:

1. Cell left Blank
2. Numbers
3. Text

[image]

**Column B - Conditional validated input**

A column that takes user's input if not blank.

---

### Question

I would like to prompt the user to input only if he selected option 1 or option 2.

If no choice is select, i.e. a blank cell, then there wouldn't be an input.

If option 1 is selected:

- The corresponding cell in `column B` would accept only a 3-digit number data type.

If option 2 is selected:

- The corresponding cell in `column B` would accept only a 10-digit text data type.

I would like the check would be based on list number, i.e. if number is 1 or if number is 2, etc.

I have a set of 10 options, so multiple conditions.

[image]

I'm using Microsoft Excel 365

### Attempt

I have tried using the below formula but I'm not sure how to allow numbers or text of specific length as an input in the corresponding cell.

```
=IF(LEFT($A$2,1)=1,<allow numbers in B2>)
```

Comment: This is not a site where you set out a list of requests and people do them for you. You need to show some effort too.

Comment: Thank you, I agree. I have changed 'request' to 'question'. I'll do more research; I don't think I'll meet deadline.

Comment: You can probably set up more data validation dependent on contents of other cells. Possibly you might need VBA. Read [ask].

Comment: The easiest solution seems to be using one column for the input of option 1 and another for option 2. So you can build the data validation normally and aggregated or use those columns as you want.

Answer (score 3):

Since your 'options' all seem to start with an integer, you could use a lengthy `SWITCH()` function for each integer case.

For the two you mentioned ('1-Numbers' and '2-Text'), the function could look like this:

```
=IFERROR(
    SWITCH(
        VALUE(LEFT($A2,1)),
        1,AND(ISNUMBER($B2),LEN($B2)=3),
        2,LEN($B2)=10
    ),TRUE
)
```

What this function does is, it checks the first character in A2 through `VALUE(LEFT($A2,1))`, then, if it is a '1', the value in B2 has to be a number and of exactly 3 characters (`AND(ISNUMBER($B2),LEN($B2)=3)`), if it is a '2', the value in B2 has to have exactly 10 characters of any type (`LEN($B2)=10`). You can simply add more cases and corresponding limitations to that and paste the formula in a custom data validation:

[image: Example Screenshot]

The `IFERROR()` statement leading the function means that if the 'option' selected does not have a specified case in the data validation, any input is allowed.

Comment: Thanks Dattel!, I want to restrict user input if it list is blank so I changed the 1st part to =IF(  AND(NOT(ISBLANK($A$2)), SWITCH ... and un-checked ignore blank. The only problem now is you can select option 1, input a valid entry i.e. 123 then change the list option to blank.

Comment: That is indeed the major problem of data validation. Unfortunately, you cannot get rid of that problem entirely through data validation alone. You will either have to use conditional formatting on top of data validation to highlight invalid selections, or use VBA to restrict it.